# How to Create Custom Single Page Workflow Approval Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, form, custom

In SharePoint Online, what I'd like to achieve as end result user experience is:

1. User creates a new item in a custom list "Payment Amount Change Request" so they can pay out more to a particular contractor, for some identified reason
2. Workflow kicks off upon item creation, sends email to User's Manager letting them know there's a request to approve, and linking them to one page where they can review the details and approve or reject the request.
3. Manager clicks the link in the email, goes to the page where the details of the request are visible, and clicks either Approve or Reject at bottom of same page. All on one page, without Manager having to link out to the item separately to see the details, or having to click "Edit Item" to Approve or Reject.

Is this possible in SharePoint Online? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Using SharePoint out of box approval workflow.
please check this below link.

http://kloudhelp.com/blog/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-online/

Thanks
Karthi

Answer (score -1):

The approval workflow in SharePoint online would be a good start. The link mentioned by Karthi can give you a basic idea to start with the workflow.
cheers